# How to make CONNECT BY parameter optional

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I have a procedure that uses `Connect By`

```
SELECT <lots of fields>
FROM Group g
  <joins>
WHERE <where>
CONNECT BY PRIOR g.ID = g.ParentID
START WITH g.ID = 1337
ORDER SIBLINGS BY g.Name
;
```

The number `1337` is a parameter on this procedure, if this value is `0` I would like to ignore the `connect by` code and execute everything else.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious answer is to test for the exception value in the `connect by` clause:

```
SELECT <lots of fields>
FROM Group g
  <joins>
WHERE <where>
CONNECT BY PRIOR g.ID = g.ParentID and :param <> 0
START WITH g.ID = :param or :param = 0
ORDER SIBLINGS BY g.Name;
```